# Cannot execute a Spanner DDL script using 'gcloud spanner databases ddl update' command

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

A Google Spanner DDL script runs successfully when submitted in the Spanner Console, but when executed via the "glcoud spanner databases ddl update" command using the "--ddl-file" argument it consistently fails with the error:

(gcloud.spanner.databases.ddl.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error parsing Spanner DDL
statement: \n : Syntax error on line 1, column 1: Encountered 'EOF' while parsing:
ddl_statement

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.LocalizedMessage
  locale: en-US
  message: |-
  Error parsing Spanner DDL statement:
  : Syntax error on line 1, column 1: Encountered 'EOF' while parsing: ddl_statement

Example of the command:

> gcloud spanner databases ddl update test-db 
> --instance=test-instance 
> --ddl-file=table.ddl

> cat table.ddl

CREATE TABLE regions
(
region_id     STRING(2)   NOT NULL,
name          STRING(13)  NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY (region_id);

There is only one other reference to this identical situation on the internet. Has anyone got the "ddl-file" argument to successfully work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is (most probably) caused by the last semi colon in your DDL script. It seems that the `--ddl-file` option accepts scripts with multiple DDL statements that may be separated by semi colons (`;`), but the last statement should not be terminated by a semi colon. Doing so will cause `gcloud` to try to parse another DDL statement after the last, only to determine that there is none, and thereby throwing an `Unexpected end of file` error.

**So TLDR: Remove the last semi colon in your script and it should work.**

Comment: Magic. Your right. I removed the semi-colon from the last ddl statement and it worked as advertised.

Comment: @RPayne Would you mind marking the answer as the accepted answer, to make it easier for others who might have the same problem to find it.